# SQL logic: sort result by product of a column and number of colums of a specific type

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, pdo

A catalog I have users can sort through by review score. Here's the SQL for grabbing the catalog by review score:

```
   SELECT *, null AS score, '0' AS SortOrder
        FROM products
        WHERE datelive < 0
   UNION
   SELECT p.*, ROUND(SUM(r.score)/COUNT(*)) AS score, '1' AS SortOrder
        FROM products p
        LEFT JOIN reviews r
            ON r.id = p.id
            AND p.datelive > 0
        GROUP BY p.id
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
    UNION
    SELECT p.*, null AS score, '2' AS SortOrder
        FROM products p
        LEFT JOIN reviews r
            ON r.id = p.id
            WHERE p.datelive > 0
        GROUP BY p.id
        HAVING COUNT(*) < 5
    ORDER BY SortOrder ASC, score DESC
```

What it does is grab the following in order:

- products of type datelive < 0
- products of type datelive > 0 and >= 5 reviews
- products of type datelive > 0 and < 5 reviews

The entire thing is also sorted by review score. I want to sort the middle bullet point by the score as it is, but multiplied by the percentage of reviews with score >= 3.53.

Say a product has a raw review score of 4.53, but two out of twenty reviews are below 3.53, that's 90% of reviews which are >= 3.53 scored. I want to sort it by `(score*mult)` where `mult` is the number of reviews >= 3.53 divided by total number of reviews. In this case, the score I'm sorting by is `4.53 * 0.9 = 4.08`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `mult` to the middle query, and put `1` as that value in the other queries. Then use `score*mult` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Also, MySQL has a built-in function for calculating an average, you don't need to divide by the count.

```
   SELECT *, null AS score, '0' AS SortOrder, 1 AS mult
        FROM products
        WHERE datelive < 0
   UNION
   SELECT p.*, ROUND(AVG(r.score)) AS score, '1' AS SortOrder,
            SUM(r.score > 3.53)/count(*) AS mult
        FROM products p
        LEFT JOIN reviews r
            ON r.id = p.id
            AND p.datelive > 0
        GROUP BY p.id
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
    UNION
    SELECT p.*, null AS score, '2' AS SortOrder, 1 AS mult
        FROM products p
        LEFT JOIN reviews r
            ON r.id = p.id
            WHERE p.datelive > 0
        GROUP BY p.id
        HAVING COUNT(*) < 5
    ORDER BY SortOrder ASC, score*mult DESC
```

Comment: What if `r.score` was actually `ROUND((SUM(r.scoreA)/COUNT(*)+SUM(r.scoreB)/COUNT(*))/2,2)`? I've tried to set `mult` as `SUM(ROUND((SUM(r.scoreA)/COUNT(*)+SUM(r.scoreB)/COUNT(*))/2,2) >= 3.53)` and I get "General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function'".

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You said you want to count the number of raw scores that are > 3.53. That's the combined score, not the raw scores.

Comment: You can't count it, because it's just one rounded value for the entire thing.

Comment: BTW, `SUM(r.score)/COUNT(*)` can be written simply as `AVG(r.score)`.

Comment: If the raw score is comprised of different components, I mean. Say a customer can review a product on price, durability, etc with different weights.

Comment: Use `SUM(r.scoreA + r.scoreB > 3.53)/COUNT(*)`.

Comment: If they have different weights, maybe `SUM(r.scoreA * weightA + r.scoreB * weightB > 3.53)/COUNT(*)`